# What is the source of the tafseer of the verse (3:37) that says rizq means scrolls of knowledge?

Tags: tafseer

In Surah Al-e-Imran, verse 37, Allah says:

[image]

The word I'm asking about here is "rizq" (second line, right at the stop). According to the mufasireen, the tafseer of this ayah is two things:

- Maryam (alayhaa salam) had out-of-season fruits with her
- She had scrolls of knowledge with her

I understand the first source of tafseer: the word rizq in Arabic language means "provision," and can encompass meanings of wealth and food.

But what about the second meaning -- scrolls of knowledge? Where or how does this meaning derive from -- is it from the language? From a correlated source (a second ayah, or a hadith)?

Comment: Nice question. I don't know about the scrolls meaning but as far as I understand "رزق" has a more general meaning than food in Quran, see for example verses 3:169 and 65:11. *Maybe* they are interpreting it as spiritual food which *can* then interpreted as knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

The word "rizq"  in Arabic language means *everything could be profitable*, so in Almou'gam Alwaseet "The Medium Dictionary"
it could mean food, wear, rain and even salary:

[image]

So "rizq" could mean beneficial knowledge.

The Prophet (Peace be Upon Him) said :

> O Allah, I seek refuge in Thee from the knowledge which does not
>   benefit, from the heart that does not entertain the fear (of Allah),
>   from the soul that does not feel contented and the supplication that
>   is not responded. [Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/urn/265680)

There is also a third tafseer mentioned in tafseer Al-Tabari, that "rizq" means increasing in the amount of food which Maryam (alayha assalam) had.
but the first tafseer (out-of-season fruits) is the most proper tafseer as mufasiroon said.